# Get FileVersionInfo interop wrapped COM dll - need full path

Tags: com, interop

I need to present an "About" style dialog about a COM dll that my .NET application is calling via interop.  I've seen solutions for using GetFileVersionInfo on a currently loaded assembly, and also pInvoke style GetModuleHandle then querying calls. But since I'm using interop, in my loaded modules list I don't see it directly, just my interop dll.

If I use FileVersionInfo(filename) and have the full path to the dll, I get exactly what I need - however as the user will have control over where they install this COM dll, I can only think of querying the registery to get this full path.  Can anyone see a better solution?  Previous version of this product was a native application and thus loaded the dll directly.

Any ideas or is querying the registry the best choice?

Comment: COM doesn't offer this info by design.  And in some cases it is entirely undiscoverable, even if you root through the registry yourself.  The server might for example be running on another machine halfway around the world.  If you know it is an in-process server then you could dig out the path to the DLL with Process.Modules